# How can I get better vectorization with GCC?

Tags: gcc, clang, sse, avx, auto-vectorization

Consider these three functions that perform the same calculation:

```
#include <x86intrin.h>

void testfunc_loop(double a, double b, double* dst)
{
    double f[] = {a,b,-a,-b};

    for(int n = 0; n < 4; ++n)
    {
        dst[n] = 0.1 + f[n]*(1.0 + 0.5*f[n]);
    }
}

void testfunc_flat(double a, double b, double* dst)
{
    dst[0] = 0.1 + ( a)*(1.0 + 0.5*( a));
    dst[1] = 0.1 + ( b)*(1.0 + 0.5*( b));
    dst[2] = 0.1 + (-a)*(1.0 + 0.5*(-a));
    dst[3] = 0.1 + (-b)*(1.0 + 0.5*(-b));
}

void testfunc_avx(double a, double b, double* dst)
{
    __m256d one      = _mm256_set1_pd(1.0);
    __m256d half     = _mm256_set1_pd(0.5);
    __m256d tenth    = _mm256_set1_pd(0.1);

    __m256d v = _mm256_set_pd(-b,-a,b,a);

    __m256d q = _mm256_add_pd(tenth,_mm256_mul_pd(v,_mm256_add_pd(one,_mm256_mul_pd(half,v))));

    _mm256_store_pd(dst,q);
}
```

GCC 4.7.2 (with -O3 -mavx) vectorizes the loop version but uses scalar operations for the unrolled loop. The (normalized) times taken by the three versions are 3.3 (loop, auto-vectorized), 1.2 (unrolled, scalar), 1 (manual avx). The performance difference between the unrolled version and the manually vectorized function is small, but I would like to force the vectorization since it is beneficial in the full code.

Testing with different compilers (see https://godbolt.org/g/HJH2CX) shows that clang vectorizes the unrolled loop automatically (since version 3.4.1) but GCC up to version 7 does not. Can I get similar vectorization automatically with GCC? I have only found optimization options related to loop vectorization which do not help. The [GCC website](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/tree-ssa/vectorization.html#slp) shows no news since 2011.

Comment: Note that filing issues in gcc's bugzilla for missed optimizations is a sensible thing to do. AVX vectorization fails because the expressions with/without negation look too different to gcc. On the other hand, it almost does SSE vectorization but rejects it as not profitable (use -fvect-cost-model=unlimited to see what it would produce), because it grossly overestimates the prologue cost (it builds the vector {a,b} at least 3 times, {1,1} twice, etc).

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=78164 for the SSE vectorization of testfunc_flat that llvm gets but not gcc.

Answer (score 5):

gcc often doesn't vectorize single-vector stuff.  I've seen similar lack-of-autovectorization with a `Point{ double x,y; }` class in an existing codebase ([Endless Sky](https://endless-sky.github.io/)).

So you may have to manually vectorize for x86 if you need it to inline to fast code.  (You might also consider passing around `__m256d` values instead of storing to arrays.)

BTW, the manually-vectorized version could be faster.  I played around with it on Godbolt, and noticed that `_mm256_set_pd(-b,-a, b,a)` was compiling to stupid code, so it would be more efficient to do it manually.    Also, if you don't have FMA available, you can reduce the latency by re-factoring the expression.  (allowing 0.1 -/+ a to happen in parallel with squaring).  [Code+asm here](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAKxAEZTUAHAvVAOwGdK0BbRvADaYA8mwDCCAIZtgmEAHIADPICUpDqgCuxZHPkBSAEwBmLADM8bTAGoA%2BgHEAcgFVbAZWHOASmOz7FAIJGxpbIAppY1vrGYng8PJYExJYAdAjRfoHBoeGR0WIAHgAcAGyJyWxpGf5BgQBuqHjo1gSYHARmmmzItgKoTBDoWgBGQtaSpNZDmqM2w5PTswBUU%2B0qNfoA7ABCNdb7UyNjZvoArLunACJRxtdb2xPzALQTT8Nbl9G7gQdRPwdmEgQRLWNg3a6KL6gm5iawAFihRl2hm2bHW/329z2vwO6HaZ1RZzut2sihStCiKOsJ3ObCJSwgtBSikp21JKVOSxphKu62M3wCvw%2BG02nyygQIAE9GJhzHZbJICEk8MNNK1bLYoJIBHhgFZ0BBjIYVCbDjMxtrdfrbIshF8NvVGs1Wu1Ot1bGYBIrBkcbBMzbNrPNxjq9bKbb7rCtVgR0UEdtj9niCATIVdweyKUjrBBxioGUyWdmyZzc5ITfaMTGCbQiRmyVmqbnhvnGczWezS0GK/zE9XzoY69EIeSOxAXq3Cx2SwyJ3yBb9kwTjEOSQ2x29J%2B3ixzZy35yKxbUgiZzJYbBxMElbDxaIYiga%2BqQEHgVHZ4oZTiVbJZL8QOneRS2IwBo3jwn7fsgkjtCBgHAegEEQH0agQC%2Bai0HGvwAPRYe%2B4FfrYl4EDegEGi%2BpDIdYeAcNYCQcBwljAFRYLAMgyDRAAYpxDoBDh1i8PwQg0UQ1iYAUugCEIbAEPxGA2AA7oQCDWBxACyAQgNYtCnMg1heq03SStY7AtAgNjIMkLBQQI1iMIqykQAAEtB8mYJJcZ8aqMkEGZxCYGA8g0dIokFEkkjWAElyXAACtcJk%2BeZll4NZtn2dYik%2BVoMlqceDRNC0bQdF0PSSHUBQ%2BuafoLJGwa2pgKzJnGWJVhq%2BElM07A2Diw54RBhFXrQ8FtooB4tTeEHNFIAhmN1JJgX1RGDSBEAlqNgoHK1E0FdJykHD180EYtQ0NmtQpjbe97NJIwwZmB/XXst/otpW637K1pGgpgwAKjd%2B3xLYBQkEN12THdR3LU8ZI9guG3jV%2BzR1BmRHECRl0QCDn3fdd844vsfH6ZghmabWKIk9sxi6U5LluQImEHDhm3w9YiN/W191DW8pAvKQ8zllC1h8axulDG04xBpIzRUKgN2KqZ1GTBlynBWJYXWBwCCaGYnp%2BmwzSA8QPG/Iz7XGVYwHhBwCRsJoHC2FNZg/bdH4ERL6BDZ1pAHd%2BPCaAIQ326QdTQ3juFQWCOV9sbzQAI5O2zrtDQZPme873u%2B0NdSTJ15s21bNt29qDvYzjAuh8FEfiq9vWHUQflDcmpDR2twqV3x67ZuF067pISydxmmYdvsncrMNXecnzgR8UKVLvJPuHrk8Ytj73vd7SSA/ZuO5ZRjmU6LzOE%2B8bhvyL7Px58ewAhGZ1xkzQltG%2B0irupXgxA0WH1I2zYiSoOM4fqTUTyapMxIiwi8awUhGAyk4MxVKxBtRCBsorTsK9/QaCogQAKNE%2BiuWIHpRUhNkBGUVllFSADHT5RdEVd0BNDK2BIWqD0PBJAVUDP6OqQZqqVQamsEUMM%2BIlAigANQABrMXaMQTQyAWDsBoqgBKeCfLBXvu0EgchsR8UMGrDWWshKTApD7AQ%2BiyEBGMa7FI%2BwKT6wsdYAAkmCBKJAjJoF9s0SRYIb6EEwPAmRYIZR4K0WEVAyAADWHBI5wxNtda6uM44LSvCjR6kxgxPRLiHLSulswU3wQZIhOYuiMFCR2Oov5vEAXvHTN6kTmgcGjhBXGrM%2BqGOBsMDG0Tnr8hxHxHSfY0CcBklHCBhc4mHQGsdDkp1YZtRqdHAu016mNIIs05atSIKTHtmk0u1gdKaSwNArAhl%2BJSEsFpawfkJZGRObQOEukzDEFQDwMW0hmg3WGJgRiZzMAXMNvTXCrlZKuOsF/MWlsEHeNkv06QMk8AzX%2BUMau35kaowfOjYM%2BtUWTEWuOKGlStleVMrLAgkgQmi2VqFeBzNSn/jMIBP%2BzoXw0Tsv%2BKiHA2ABW8mZfiSUUp2R8ikXpsiBnVKBVA7xhErTMI4CEkZiKEnjOsKQMkCrIYWK5lDF6RthXXVsFYYAMTFnfn1i0jGmhRUowYnqSVIScZ8WQMctghhia3PuY89pPz9h9PaPKaZ20fJr2uF7e6S0DQnQ1VMraScEA50tpYfO%2Bq5qpwVOgN2y1I2TG1bq7GUJbX2sddYbJEBznoGIZIIykgzIS1vmraOmhJB%2BTcW0X2sY%2BwRJ9X5DgTaZVJpTQaSN0a862wxrUuZZgIIlz4p0S8NFkEqNmfbSOibVF12Wg3T5HaBDNt7FkUUPEeJ8XkiQS8pl7maGAAgRgwD8U4PBbQvJSE2g0XVprT0jEPK4UYH5JURlWnNBhSYllQK2ClUkIIa6QhJhtEYLZPy1g3AAGkAAy6VfJ%2BmTcerQZ6L3QunYemwCUwSGL3bhAIAh0FvKVOCkyARVLXAgNFQQspkh1HBRBG6S6bD%2BMBMQZh3Q5invTbrU2V8tL3humJTAyA1SsDBF0QgQU2CSnkqWuMeVnSFTdD0QCrCLRcMDLVX0PDm3bphlUi6D5xi/QTTwe6iSDSpP5rE35GTW0fVqbW%2Btccbzp0eikjpbIum4R6edVzNa63hntp55ZBo3NhfQKDf64MQ0TJtYFymOUmpVk9UKszamdqYis0G8ZGEw2mY%2Bn2xgFtHaeYTqmwmycLOTNK5dX1UaB2O1ZoRGYic6sIHTX591WyhYtG0DAny1FmIiQIAekxHBJh%2BSeEMD599DEsAq5KZJwCwjSCYiLVl7KXPNZwRmcrlX9VUhi/WkdDmJ1fw4DYotlywS0FoLpSQZhWh4PCs8oMC7rPsfru0SYODGveo%2Bi%2BM9x2es3ljYO3653QuXfnZ0vi2p0EPdgc95A6zJCipgScplYKkFKVMjYeRvkTG/cIrXTAAOUwokMOs3UCBNmOcc0AmSl9r5WDVtT2y4KglFPG4wVA9EVR2kri3AIqgKIKFOPIUgbAFC0Hl6gBQYgkTZg0NoXQlJjDK9IAQBQygTSkBCSAU4igZfyDhPLngdBFCW8V0oFXCh5dcEt4b53KEYBQB96hFADzBLePINwQPDHiAgGACUBnFgN3eK4BAYYRv5e8B4HV0QV9k%2BkHwH5aReBmNcGd%2BQaSblk9qCYL4wvTxxLWCeAAdQQbXuvKsKVPGYWVWvwhjC17MMx4gwwReYBeJbHvZhoIEDb2lNvBAuiYGHFIDgrlJK1%2BYTodItwF9L4ENLgQsv5dO%2BUAwBQwQKTIOKCUJ4JQ4TWCGyUFIhh5ee%2BN2oM3Furc29IHboocJmQlFKIYTYOEC3AATiKEUGMGAIVyz1V3kDdxAA9zL1IDgFgCQCyiwxDwgAEnDzoFIFlEIBIDoDUF33kDlygKLxgJP3SmJ3P0v2v1v3v0fzLyIIUA/zt20hSGAL12ME2E/DhGAMUFoGAJKEUBKDIMPxgLgIQK9xf3N0t2IOMH32gNdwNyYKtwfzEJd1gJUOkMDnj2kxADhCAA)

```
// 0.1 + a  + 0.5*a*a   =  0.1 +   a  * (1.0 + 0.5*a)
//     + b
// 0.1 - a  + 0.5*a*a   =  0.1 + (-a) * (1.0 - 0.5*a)
//     - b

// only one of the mul+add pairs can fuse into an FMA
// but 0.1+/-a happens in parallel with 0.5*a*a, so it's lower latency without FMA
void testfunc_latency_without_fma(double a, double b, double* dst)
{
  // 6 AVX instructions other than the store:
  // 2 shuffles, 1 mul, 1 FMA, 1 add.  1 xor.  In theory could run one iteration per 2 clocks
    __m256d abab       = _mm256_setr_pd(a, b, a, b);    // 1c + 3c latency (unpck + vinsertf128)
    __m256d sq256      = _mm256_mul_pd(abab, abab);     // 5c
    const __m256d half = _mm256_set1_pd(0.5);
    __m256d sq_half256 = _mm256_mul_pd(sq256, half);    // 5c: dependency chain 1 ready in 14c from a and b being ready

    // we could use a smaller constant if we do _mm256_setr_m128d(ab, xor(ab, set1(-0.))
    // but that takes an extra vinsertf128 and this part isn't the critical path.
    const __m256d upper_signmask = _mm256_setr_pd(0. ,0. ,-0. ,-0.);
    __m256d ab_negab = _mm256_xor_pd(abab, upper_signmask); // chain2: 1c from abab

    const __m256d tenth   = _mm256_set1_pd(0.1);
    __m256d tenth_plusminus_ab = _mm256_add_pd(tenth, ab_negab); // chain2: 3c (ready way ahead of squared result)

    __m256d result = _mm256_add_pd(tenth_plusminus_ab, sq_half256);  // fuses with the sq_half
    _mm256_store_pd(dst, result);
}
```

---

IDK why the auto-vectorized loop was so slow when you tested.  It does scalar stores into the array and then a vector load, incurring a ~11 cycle store-forwarding stall.  So it has much higher latency than either of the other two ways, but IDK if that should affect throughput.  IDK how you were testing; maybe you were using the result of one call as input to the next?  Or maybe repeated store-forwarding stalls on the same chunk of stack space are a problem?

---

In general for larger arrays, gcc really likes pointers to be aligned.  It generates giant fully-unrolled scalar intro/outro code to reach an aligned pointer, and then uses aligned stores/loads.

This doesn't help much for modern CPUs (but doesn't usually hurt much either), especially for data that's *usually* aligned at run-time, but is maybe good if the data is usually unaligned, or it's running on a pre-Nehalem CPU.

IDK if this has anything to do with gcc's reluctance to auto-vectorize small things, but telling it that the `double*` was aligned didn't seem to help.

I think part of the problem is that it's not great at inserting shuffles to vectorize code that needs shuffling.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. I was testing the functions in a loop with repeated calls with the same arguments and summing the results. It seems I will have to stick to manual vectorization.